# A 3D-curve without axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I have the following set:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [x=1.2cm,y=1.2cm,z=0.5cm,scale=1.0,>=stealth]   
    % Grid
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
        \draw [black!20] (-2.5,-2.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
    % Axis ticks
    \foreach \c in {1,2,...,2}
        {\node[] at (-\c,-0.4) {\footnotesize $-$\c};}
    \foreach \c in {1,2,...,2}
        {\node[] at (\c,-0.3) {\footnotesize \c};}
    \foreach \c in {1,2,...,2}
        {\node[] at (-0.3,-\c) {\footnotesize $-$\c};}
    \foreach \c in {1,2,...,2}
        {\node[] at (-0.3,\c) {\footnotesize \c};}
    \end{scope}

    % The axes
    \draw[->, thick] (xyz cs:x=-2.5) -- (xyz cs:x=2.5) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (xyz cs:z=-2.5) -- (xyz cs:z=2.5) node[above] {\small $y$};
    \draw[-] (xyz cs:y=-2.3) -- (xyz cs:y=2.3) node[above] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can we draw a **3D-curve** like

```
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=0:1] (t^2,{ t*(1-t)}, 1-t);
```

but **without** using `axis` environment? Maybe there is something else instead of `addplot3`?

**Update:** I figured it out: We simply need to use `draw + plot` like this

```
\draw[solid, red] plot[domain=-1:1, samples=200, smooth]
    ({\x*\x-1},{4*\x*cos(90*\x)},{-\x});
```

And that's all :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? No axis? Please clarify what you're after.

Comment: @TeXnician thank you for the comment, I've added some details.

Comment: Are you aware of the `hide axis` option, i.e. does `\begin{axis}[hide axis]
     \addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=0:1] ({t^2},{ t*(1-t)}, 1-t);
 \end{axis}` do what you want?

Comment: @marmot When I use standard `axis` with `view` parameter in 3D, it rotates the x-axis (it becomes not horizontal). I would like to have horizontal x-axis in 3D, but I do not know how to achieve that.

Comment: The sequence `\begin{axis}[ view={120}{00},hide axis]
    \addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=0:1] ({t^2},{ t*(1-t)}, 1-t);
\end{axis}` makes the x axis point to the right. How about you show us what you have tried and indicate what you want?